# PIC16f84 program memory question

Tags: pic

Why does the program memory of the said pic contains 1K x 14 where in fact it only contains 13 bit of instructions. Specifically, where does the 1 bit go out of the 14 bit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're getting confused between the word size and the program-counter size:

> The PIC16FXX has a 13-bit program counter capable
>   of addressing an 8K x 14 program memory space. For
>   the PIC16F84A, the first 1K x 14 (0000h-03FFh) are
>   physically implemented (

So you can have 13 bits worth of addressing to get at 8K of 14-bit words.

As you can see in the data sheet, the full 14 bits of each word is used:

[image: Program word format]

Answer (score 2):

Said PIC *does* contain program memory words that are 14 bits wide.  It so happens, but is completely orthogonal, that the basic PIC 16 architecture allows for up to 8192 instruction words.  Since 8192 = 2^13, a program memory *address* on a PIC 16 is up to 13 bits wide.  In addition to that, the PIC 16F84, which is one particular implementation of the PIC 16 architecture, happens to have only 1024 = 2^10 program memory words (only 1/8 of the possible program memory is implemented on that particular part).  So on a PIC 16F84, the program memory addresses can be thought of as only 10 bits wide.

By the way, you should return the 16F84 to whatever museum you found it in.  There are PIC available today that cost less, have more peripherals, have more memory, and come in the same package as the ancient 16F84.

Comment: Ah... I remember the good ol' 84...  First PIC I ever used.   It soon got relegated to the electronic centipede farm in the sky, to be replaced by the slightly better (and cheaper) 16F88.

Comment: Indeed, a lot of 'old' projects show a PIC16F84 but they cost a relative fortune nowadays to buy.

Answer (score 0):

A 13-bit program counter can address 2^13 or 8192 memory locations (14-bit instructions). Only 1k (1024) of those locations have actually been implemented on the 16F84.